# RegisterConfirmation failing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am using the ASP.NET Core Identity scaffold (in a Blazor server app, but Identity is MVC). I added SendGrid and got it to send the register confirmation email. However, when I click on the link for the email, I get an error.

```
https://localhost:7229/Identity/Account/RegisterConfirmation?userId=a58fb381-4981-4b90-909c-1687e4f1b1b8&code=Q2ZESjhENFdLSkl5blRoTmxvelhBc3h2WGQ4VmNLOHdVbVJ0RkNYTE5RS1RZZXRtc1F5cTh5TFJFb2dRS2d4NXFjbGtiK1hIWDZrTVBDaTlQY3ZoZ2dDdi8zR1ZUbGVxbGQ4Mk8zZVFwYmFoUTBvRWJ2SmtjanZlTmdmQThXbDJidEtUdVcxZTlrNTVid2FvVUgyVzRSSElZMlpib3BKcHFsTTNNcms4OW5sUjdCV2ZEaFNoOHlxRnNBVUJQbGZ6dE1QNHhVOEpYcFpGaFBJWmpwWFlCcEhFTGhFODZ3QWtnOXM0NnVnQWd5Z2pOS2hiVjZGUW4xYWpDMGR3TG1YWlk4MHZadz09&returnUrl=%2fidentity%2faccount%2fLogin
```

I get the error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: No page named '/Index' matches the supplied values.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.RedirectToPageResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, RedirectToPageResult result)
```

Looking at the source for RegisterConfirmation.cshtml.cs I found the problem:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string email, string returnUrl = null)
        {
            if (email == null)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("/Index");
            }
```

email is null and so it is trying to redirect. The question is why the exception. If I go to the browser and put in https://localhost:7272/Index then I get the MainLayout and "Sorry, there's nothing at this address." as the @Body - which is reasonable. So why does this blow up?

And does this mean I need to instantiate every Identity window and fix the RedirectToPage() line?

Answer (score 0):

The scaffolding, or the project template, or both, have a bug.  In my case it was a malformed link causing `code` to be null causing redirect to the (what I'm chalking up as) unknown `/Index` page causing the error.  When I view in a browser `/Index` I get spawise application startup as expected, the only MVC Index page is within IdentityServer tree.  I checked the IdentityServer scaffoldings, they reference it, and there is one `\Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\Manage\Index.cshtml`.  It's either a bug in the templates or some default configuration setting in MVC is inconsistently applying.

The code being hit, for my case was in `\Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\RegisterConfirmation.cshtml.cs`:

```
            if (userId == null || code == null)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("/Index");
            }
```

For some reason that page was removed or renamed or "supposed to be created" or there's a scope problem or something.  It's strange because these templates are supposed to work out of the box and I don't think I tampered with the existence or naming of any MVC pages.

Comment: I think going to "/Index is trying to go to the root Index.html and there is an Index.razor in Blazor so it should all work. But RedirectToPage() may only work for MVC pages.